# UserInteractive=True while running on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am using a library in my web project that behaves normally while debugging through Visual Studio having the Server parameter set to IIS Express. When I switch to Local IIS, the module in the library returns an exception that it cannot start. 
From what I can extract so far, it must have something to do with property UserInteractive being false in local IIS. I also get the Exception

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation.
```

when trying to show a form in Local IIS mode. The constructor of the external library module takes a window handle as one of its arguments. While I never use the parts of the library that demand user interaction, it crashes.

How can I maintain the execution environment in Local IIS the same as in IIS Express?

Comment: If it's expecting a window handle and/or attempting to show dialog boxes (which the error indicates it *is* attempting to do), I'd say it's safe to say it's *not* designed to be used in service/IIS environments. The solution isn't to get IIS running with UserInteractive true, it's to pick a different tool/library that *is* supported in service contexts.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I understand what you say but I am afraid this is not an option. The library is included with the ERP my company uses. It is supposed to give us access to all ERP back-office processes. In order to change the library, the ERP must come first.

Comment: Hey Saloom how did you overcome with the problem?

Comment: @AvishekhBharati Hi, I did not manage to solve it directly. From my research back then I could not find a solution to allow server-side code to show forms. I resorted in hosting the desired code in a separate application and having the web-site + the app communicating through IPC. Never had a problem since then. It is working flawlessly for many years.

Comment: @Saloom Wow, I am trying to implement MSAL to overcome two factor Auth in the existing application which is written in asp.net web form. It works fine locally in VS but not when deployed in IIS. I am not sure now how to overcome this problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AvishekhBharati I am not sure how you are trying to implement things and what exactly is your error message. Have you asked a question here on SO with more details related to your problem?

Comment: @Saloom Yep I asked. But no replies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429701/why-app-is-throwing-error-in-test-environment-but-working-fine-in-local-machine