# Why app is throwing error in test environment but working fine in local machine using ASP.NET Web Forms and MSAL?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, azure-ad-msal

**Scenario:**

Using the application, customer can access the emails in within the application and decide to save it. I have used **Exchange Web Service Managed API** for this. Things were working fine until IT implemented Multi factor Authentication. Now the program cannot access the mailbox based on the username and password.

**Solution**

In order to overcome this issue I integrated MSAL(Microsoft Authentication Library) to acquire the Access token in order to use it with the EWS Managed API to access the emails. I have registered an application in the Azure and used the clientID and TenentID. It works perfectly fine when testing locally. But throws an error when deploying in dev/test environnment. I am not sure what to do. Could you please help me with this?

```html
    Private Function GetDelegatedExService() As ExchangeService

        If Session("EwsOAuthToken") Is Nothing Then
            Dim caller As New AsyncGetToken(AddressOf GetDelegatedToken)
            ' Initiate the asynchronous call.
            Dim result As IAsyncResult = caller.BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)

            ' thread from any process ready to run and has a higher priority then Sleep(0) will yield the processor and let it run
            Thread.Sleep(0)

            ' Perform additional processing here and then wait for the WaitHandle to be signaled.
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()

            ' Call EndInvoke to retrieve the results.
            Dim returnValue As String = caller.EndInvoke(result)
            Session("EwsOAuthToken") = returnValue
        End If

        Dim ewsClient = New ExchangeService()
        ewsClient.Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")


        Dim myToken = Session("EwsOAuthToken").ToString()
        ' Setup OAuthCredentials with the token
        ewsClient.Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(myToken)

        Return ewsClient

    End Function




    Private Function GetDelegatedToken() As String

        Dim pcaOptions = New PublicClientApplicationOptions() With
            {
                .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("appId"),
                .TenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("tenantId")
            }

        Dim redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EBWebURL")

        Dim pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder _
        .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions) _
        .WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl) _
        .Build()

        ' The permission scope required for EWS access
        Dim token = OpenAuthPopup(pca).GetAwaiter().GetResult()

        Return token
    End Function




    Private Async Function OpenAuthPopup(pca As PublicClientApplication) As Tasks.Task(Of String)
        Dim ewsScopes = {"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All"}
        Dim authResult = Await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync()
        Return authResult.AccessToken

    End Function
```

This is the local testing where user is able to get the login by Microsoft account prompt. They have to enter their organization account details, gets the Multi Factor Auth code in phone, adds in the prompt and then gets authenticated(it simply returns a access token).

[image]

But when the code is deployed to DEV/TEST environment. I get the following error. It is not even prompting for the Microsoft Login. And I tried searching for the given error, but not able to figure out what the problem actually is with the asp.net web app or Microsoft Auth Library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with the technologies you describe in your question but I will try to give you my persepctive on the issue. From what I can understand, the code you have pasted here is supposed to run on the web-server. Testing the application locally, the client is requesting information from the web-server but the web-server needs first to aqcuire an authentication token. The modal window that appears on the screen, asking from the client to authenticate, seems to be fired by

```
pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync()
```

This code runs on the web-server and it is the web-server that shows this pop-up. The clients can only enter their credentials because the testing is taking place on the same machine where the web-server lives. In produciton environments, web app code is not allowed to open a modal window. Even if it was permitted, there would be no one there to interact with the pop-up.

I checked the MSIL library and I found that `PublicClientApplication` contains more authentication methods and some of them are non-interactive, such as `AquireTokenByUsernamePassword`. I am not sure how you can handle the code received by the user's mobile. I cannot help any further on the library since I am not familiar with it.

Another option might be to make the client-browser open a pop-up window on `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All` and somehow return the authorization token back to the web-server. You might want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/markyroden/o365Token) and see if it suits your needs.