# How can I verify if username and password is correct despite of Multifactor authentication is enabled with Azure AD?

Tags: authentication, webforms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am wondering if there is anyway to check if the entered username and password is correct despite of enforcing **multi factor authentication in Azure Active Directory**?
I have set up an app with application permission(with admin consent) as well as delegated permission and is able to test both approach using ConfidentialClient and PublicClient using MSAL library.

I am not able to run my web form app in IIS with the PublicClient approach which is interactive and displays you a popup for the Microsoft login. So, the only approach I see here is to use app-only authentication.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth )

I can use the confidential client(app only) since I have all the required admin consents granted to get the OAuth token and then impersonate the user to access to EWS managed api.

But the requirement is the user should enter their outlook password in the webform app before loading their emails(from EWS Managed API which needs OAuth token).

At this point I am not sure what to do next. Please help. Also let me know if you need more information.

*For more reference why I am no able to use delegated authentication: [Why app is throwing error in test environment but working fine in local machine using ASP.NET Web Forms and MSAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429701/why-app-is-throwing-error-in-test-environment-but-working-fine-in-local-machine)*

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want to check the username and password by Azure AD first and using the confidential client to call APIs on behalf of the user.

This way is something hacking, but I think it works for this scenario. Just try the request below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Request Body:

```
client_id=<confidential client app id>
&Client_secret=<confidential client app sec>
&grant_type=password
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
&username=<username>
&password=<password>
```

If the user typed the wrong user name and password, the response would be:
[image]

If username and password are all right, the response report the MFA related info:

[image]